# Override angularJS createInjector method

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to override the method createInjector in angularJS?

Context: I have really huge (realy realy huge) application that is splitted in modules, some features have dependency from another module classes. But, most of the time, I dont want to load these dependency modules cause they will not be loaded in my development environment. So, when my application as to load these modules I would like to return an empty object instead of a exception that breaks my application.

:)

THank you!
(angular version: 1.4.8)

Comment: What is the "method createInjector"?

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple: create in your enviroment a javascript file in wich you can define empty modules like below

```
//empty.js
angular.module('feature1', [])
angular.module('feature2', [])
```

maybe you can wrap all features' name in an array and then create a module for each feature in a for loop

ps: insert it in .ignore :P